# sending data in a secure way

Tags: web-services, security, encryption, get

I want to send some data using GET over http. I want to decrypt or scramble it for security reasons so instead of sending: http://www.website.com/service?a=1&b=2&b=3
i want it to look like http://www.website.com/service?data=sdoicvyencvkljnsdpio
and inside the service to be able to decrypt the message and get the real data.

What is the best approach for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SSL and certificates. You can see it works here: http://mattfleming.com/node/289. You can find various tutorials on how to do that based on for your specific web-server.

Comment: the server is written in .NET and exposes a WCF service where each service method is exposed in the way of an http GET. the client apps are WP7, iPhone, Android and Symbian. that is why i chose the HTTP get

Comment: In this case you will find the followings usefull:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=486 http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=487

Answer (score 1):

What laguage are you in? If php you could look up on the [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) functions.

But seriosly. Probably a better way for that would be to use HTTPS, which was designed for that.

I don't know about your application but it could have relevance.

Another common tequnique is the secure token teqnique where you basically generate a hash of your params and a secret token. The token is the only thing not included in the url. At the other end you re-create that hash with the same secret token and see if itmatches. This way youc an compile security methods like IP validation, time to live timestamps or signing a request by a user.

A more advanced method is the HTTP Digest authentication

Comment: the server is written in .NET and exposes a WCF service where each service method is exposed in the way of an http GET. the client apps are WP7, iPhone, Android and Symbian. that is why i chose the HTTP get.

Answer (score 1):

SSL and POSTing the data would be a sensible way to approach this, but if you must do it with GET you can still keep it fairly secure

The [MCrypt libraries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php) for PHP are very good, then on the receiving page you would need a checksum to be absolutely sure that the string passed hasn't been tampered with.